# Amazon RDS Postgres Queries Slow On 250 GB table

Tags: sql, postgresql, amazon-rds

Thanks in advance!

I realize that all the time, companies work (quickly) with enormous, huge datasets.

I have a large dataset (~1.6 billion rows) I am trying to perform some joins on (joins with smaller tables primarily by date). The problem is, the query seems to never finish. As in, it’s been running for 24+ hours and still won’t finish. I’ve tried tweaking some Postgres parameters (maybe not the right ones), building an index on date in the big table, and still cannot get query performance to be reasonable.

Before you say “gee, what a terrible question, you didn’t even post the query,” I want to start with a simpler example of the issue.

If I have 15 years of daily data (maybe 100,000 rows per day), and I simply perform, for instance:

```
select * from my_table where datadate = ‘04/10/2018’ limit 10;
```

The query will take somewhere around 30 minutes, which to me is nuts. I get it’s a lot of data to sift through. I’ve tried doubling the ram/CPU on the RDS instance, but performance doesn’t improve at all. It’s identical. I don’t know how to get Postgres to actually use all the ram and CPU.

I’ve thought about partitioning on date, but the main thing I need to do with the table is do a full table join into several other tables on date, with some where criteria thrown in. I’ve heard partitioning in that sense might not help that much.

Does anyone have any advice? I’m at a loss, and slightly on a deadline. I’d really, really appreciate the help!

Update: turns out, I had not indexed correctly (or at least, I thought the indexing had completed, but it seemed the indexes never actually got created). Redoing the indexes overnight dropped the execution time of that select statement down to a few miliseconds, which is a dramatic improvement.

The true query I am trying to accomplish is:

```
drop table if exists table1;
create temporary table table1 as
  select
    [several different fields]
    round(coalesce (multiplier, 1) * fieldA, 2) as adjustedFieldA,
    [Several different fields]
  from big
  inner join
    smallA
  on
    datadate = smallA.date
  inner join
    smallB
  on
    underlyingsymbol = smallB.symbol
  left join
    smallC
  on
    underlyingsymbol = smallC.symbol
  and
    datadate < smallC.splitdate
  and
    smallC.splitdate < smallB.paedate
  where
    smallB.paedate > datadate
  and
    (select count(*) from calendar
    where datadate < calendar.tradingdate
    and calendar.tradingdate <= paedate) < 30
  and
      expiration > smallB.paedate
  and
    smallB.status = 'Verified'
  and
    type = 'X'
  and
    criteriaA > 0
  and
      criteriaB > 0
  and
    criteriaC > 0
  and
    abs(underlyingprice-criteriaD)/underlyingprice < .2
;
```

The EXPLAIN command output for the true query I am trying to accomplish is (assume indexes on big.datadate and big.underlyingsymbol):

```
"Nested Loop  (cost=6856.00..512101834349.94 rows=77115662 width=117)"
"  Join Filter: (big.datadate = small_data.date)"
"  ->  Hash Left Join  (cost=6856.00..507817952718.73 rows=77096760 width=80)"
"        Hash Cond: ((big.underlyingsymbol)::text = (split_data.symbol)::text)"
"        Join Filter: ((big.datadate < split_data.splitdate) AND (small1.splitdate < esmall2.otherdate))"
"        ->  Hash Join  (cost=6802.26..507814169121.84 rows=77096760 width=74)"
"              Hash Cond: ((big.underlyingsymbol)::text = (small.symbol)::text)"
"              Join Filter: ((small.otherdate > big.datadate) AND (big.expiration > small.otherdate) AND ((SubPlan 1) < 30))"
"              ->  Seq Scan on big  (cost=0.00..76749439.60 rows=96205127 width=64)"
"                    Filter: ((factorA > '0'::numeric) AND (factorB > '0'::numeric) AND (factorC > '0'::numeric) AND ((type)::text = 'factorD'::text) AND ((abs((factorE - factorF)) / factorE) < 0.2))"
"              ->  Hash  (cost=4636.43..4636.43 rows=173267 width=14)"
"                    ->  Seq Scan on small  (cost=0.00..4636.43 rows=173267 width=14)"
"                          Filter: ((status)::text = 'Verified'::text)"
"              SubPlan 1"
"                ->  Aggregate  (cost=243.88..243.89 rows=1 width=8)"
"                      ->  Seq Scan on small3  (cost=0.00..243.72 rows=63 width=0)"
"                            Filter: ((big.datadate < otherdate2) AND (otherdate2 <= small.otherdate))"
"        ->  Hash  (cost=31.66..31.66 rows=1766 width=14)"
"              ->  Seq Scan on small3  (cost=0.00..31.66 rows=1766 width=14)"
"  ->  Materialize  (cost=0.00..76.56 rows=3704 width=9)"
"        ->  Seq Scan on small4  (cost=0.00..58.04 rows=3704 width=9)"
```

(Had to scrub some column names) It doesn't appear to utilize the indexes though? It has been running for 2 days now and I don't think it's making much progress.... Does anyone know how to speed it up?

Also, the output of psql \d is:

```
              Table "public.big"
      Column      |       Type        | Collation | Nullable | Default 
------------------+-------------------+-----------+----------+---------
 underlyingsymbol | character varying |           | not null | 
 6 more columns.... 
 datadate         | date              |           | not null | 
 12 more columns...
Indexes:
    "big_datadate_underlyingsymbol_idx" btree (datadate, underlyingsymbol)
Check constraints:
    "check_types" CHECK (type::text = 'type1'::text OR type::text = 'type2'::text)
```

Comment: First of all, using `LIMIT` without `ORDER BY` is somewhat meaningless, because are not telling Postgres _which_ 10 records you actually want to see.  This aside, have you looked into adding an index to your table?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen As OP said, building an index has been tried. @kmypwn Could you perhaps show us the complete output of ```psql``` command ```\d my_table```? 1.6 billion entries should not be too much of a problem with a proper index..

Comment: Also, we need some execution plans. Ideally `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS)`, but if that doesn't finish, plain `EXPLAIN` will have to do. Perhaps you need something better than a hosted machine.

Comment: Thank you all SO much for your advice. I have added answers to them above towards the end of the question.

Comment: *"Perhaps you need something better than a hosted machine"* People most of the time do not know that on Amazon RDS they share cpu cycles and memory/disk I/O with other people aswell which are running on the same physical machine..  Performance can really depend on time there..

Comment: Did you try converting the type of '04/..' in your where clause to match the column?

Comment: .. also something is not right here, that plan can not be from that simple select.. Or the wrong query is posted or the wrong explain.. When looking at the plan in would expect seeing a query with JOIN(s) with GROUP BY usage somewhere..

Comment: Sorry-- I was not clear! That plan is not from a simple select, that is from a much larger query I am trying to accomplish. Adding that now.